# UNity3d Adding a value via button and getting random results

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i found my next tier 1 problem and hoping for some help here in the so called internet.
first of all here are my atm not to hard to understanding codes.
please tell me if im doing something wrong here on stackoverflow im an absolute newbie and dont know how to explain my problem in this case without post a bunch of code :(

i know there are much ways to improve mystuff but im in the learning process and for now its maybe enough to tell my why the behavior of my code didnt match my expectations.

This is my PlayerClass:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Values : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float MaxNrg;
    public float Nrg;
    public float NrgDrain;
    public float NrgDrainCoef;
    public float NrgInPercent;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
        MaxNrg = 7950.0f;
        Nrg = 7950.0f;
        NrgDrain = 0.09201389f;
        NrgDrainCoef = 1.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {

    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        NrgInPercent = (GETnrg() / GETmaxnrg()) * 100;
    }

    public void SETmaxnrg(float tmpfloat)
    {
        MaxNrg = tmpfloat;
    }
    public void SETnrg(float tmpfloat)
    {
        Nrg = tmpfloat;
    }    
    public void SETnrgdrain(float tmpfloat)
    {
        NrgDrain = tmpfloat;
    }    
    public void SETnrgdraincoef(float tmpfloat)
    {
        NrgDrainCoef = tmpfloat;
    }
    public void ADDmaxnrg(float tmpfloat)
    {
        MaxNrg += tmpfloat;
    }     
    public void ADDnrg(float tmpfloat)
    {
        Nrg += tmpfloat;
    }    
    public void ADDnrgdrain(float tmpfloat)
    {
        NrgDrain += tmpfloat;
    }    
    public void ADDnrgdraincoef(float tmpfloat)
    {
        NrgDrainCoef += tmpfloat;
    }
    public float GETmaxnrg()
    {
        return MaxNrg;
    }    
    public float GETnrg()
    {
        return Nrg;
    }
    public float GETnrgdrain()
    {
        return NrgDrain;
    }
    public float GETnrgdraincoef()
    {
        return NrgDrainCoef;
    }
    public float GETnrginpercent()
    {
        return NrgInPercent;
    }
}
```

End Here are the "Drain_mechanics":

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Drain_Mechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool drainstate = false;

    public double NrgLeftInSeconds;

    public GameObject Scriptcontainer_Player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player = GameObject.Find("Scriptcontainer_Player");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(drainstate == true)
        {
            Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().Nrg -= Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrgdrain() * Time.deltaTime * Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrgdraincoef();
        }
        else if(drainstate == false)
        {

        }

        NrgLeftInSeconds = Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrg() / (Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrgdrain() * Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrgdraincoef());

    }
    public void SETdrainstate(bool tmpdrainstate)
    {
        drainstate = tmpdrainstate;
    }
    public double GETnrgleftinseconds()
    {
        return NrgLeftInSeconds;
    }
}
```

Class for initializing the input fields in the game:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Initialize_InputFields : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Input_Energy;
    public GameObject Input_Drainrate;
    public GameObject Input_DrainCoef;

    public float InputNrg;
    public float InputNrgDrainrate;
    public float InputNrgDrainCoef;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
        Input_Energy    = GameObject.Find("Input_Energy");
        Input_Drainrate = GameObject.Find("Input_Drainrate");
        Input_DrainCoef = GameObject.Find("Input_DrainCoef");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        InputNrg            = float.Parse(Input_Energy.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
        InputNrgDrainrate   = float.Parse(Input_Drainrate.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
        InputNrgDrainCoef   = float.Parse(Input_DrainCoef.GetComponent<InputField>().text);
    }
    public float GETinputnrg()
    {
        return InputNrg;
    }
    public float GETinputnrgdrainrate()
    {
        return InputNrgDrainrate;
    }    
    public float GETinputnrgdraincoef()
    {
        return InputNrgDrainCoef;
    }
}
```

a class to manipulate the textfields while the game is running

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Display_LabelsCalculated : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Scriptcontainer_Player;
    public GameObject Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics;

    public GameObject Display_Energy;
    public GameObject Display_EnergyDrain;
    public GameObject Display_EnergyDrainCoef;
    public GameObject Display_EnergyTimeleft;
    public GameObject Display_EnergyPercentleft;

    public Text Display_Energy_Text;
    public Text Display_EnergyDrain_Text;
    public Text Display_EnergyDrainCoef_Text;
    public Text Display_EnergyTimeleft_Text;
    public Text Display_EnergyPercentleft_Text;
        

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player          = GameObject.Find("Scriptcontainer_Player");
        Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics   = GameObject.Find("Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics");

        Display_Energy              = GameObject.Find("Display_Energy");
        Display_EnergyDrain         = GameObject.Find("Display_EnergyDrain");
        Display_EnergyDrainCoef     = GameObject.Find("Display_EnergyDrainCoef");
        Display_EnergyTimeleft      = GameObject.Find("Display_EnergyTimeleft");
        Display_EnergyPercentleft   = GameObject.Find("Display_EnergyPercentleft");


        Display_Energy_Text             = Display_Energy.GetComponent<Text>();
        Display_EnergyDrain_Text        = Display_EnergyDrain.GetComponent<Text>();
        Display_EnergyDrainCoef_Text    = Display_EnergyDrainCoef.GetComponent<Text>();
        Display_EnergyTimeleft_Text     = Display_EnergyTimeleft.GetComponent<Text>();
        Display_EnergyPercentleft_Text  = Display_EnergyPercentleft.GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        int hours = (int)(Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics.GetComponent<Drain_Mechanics>().GETnrgleftinseconds() / 60) / 60;
        int minutes = (int)(Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics.GetComponent<Drain_Mechanics>().GETnrgleftinseconds() / 60) % 60;
        int seconds = (int)Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics.GetComponent<Drain_Mechanics>().GETnrgleftinseconds() % 60;

        Display_EnergyTimeleft_Text.text = hours.ToString() + ":" + ((minutes < 10) ? ("0") : ("")) + minutes.ToString() + ":" + ((seconds < 10) ? ("0") : ("")) + seconds.ToString();

        Display_Energy_Text.text = Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrg().ToString();
        Display_EnergyDrain_Text.text = Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrgdrain().ToString();
        Display_EnergyDrainCoef_Text.text = Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrgdraincoef().ToString();
        Display_EnergyPercentleft_Text.text = Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().GETnrginpercent().ToString();
    }
}
```

followed by some button mechanics

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Button_Mechanics : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Scriptcontainer_Player;
    public GameObject Scriptcontainer_InputFields;
    public GameObject Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics;

    public Button Button_SetEnergy;
    public Button Button_SetDrainCoef;
    public Button Button_SetDrainrate;
    public Button Button_AddEnergy;
    public Button Button_AddDrainCoef;
    public Button Button_AddDrainrate;
    public Button Button_ActivateMechanics;
    public Button Button_DeactivateMechanics;
    public Button Button_ResetValues;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public void Start()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player          = GameObject.Find("Scriptcontainer_Player");
        Scriptcontainer_InputFields     = GameObject.Find("Scriptcontainer_InputFields");
        Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics   = GameObject.Find("Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics");

        Button_SetEnergy                = GameObject.Find("Button_SetEnergy").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_SetDrainCoef             = GameObject.Find("Button_SetDrainCoef").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_SetDrainrate             = GameObject.Find("Button_SetDrainrate").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_AddEnergy                = GameObject.Find("Button_AddEnergy").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_AddDrainCoef             = GameObject.Find("Button_AddDrainCoef").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_AddDrainrate             = GameObject.Find("Button_AddDrainrate").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_ActivateMechanics        = GameObject.Find("Button_ActivateMechanics").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_DeactivateMechanics      = GameObject.Find("Button_DeactivateMechanics").GetComponent<Button>();
        Button_ResetValues              = GameObject.Find("Button_ResetValues").GetComponent<Button>();
    }
    public void Update()
    {

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Button_SetEnergy.onClick.AddListener(SETnrgbtnclk);
        Button_SetDrainCoef.onClick.AddListener(SETnrgdraincoefbtnclk);
        Button_SetDrainrate.onClick.AddListener(SETnrgdrainbtnclk);
        Button_AddEnergy.onClick.AddListener(ADDnrgbtnclk);
        Button_AddDrainCoef.onClick.AddListener(ADDnrgdraincoefbtnclk);
        Button_AddDrainrate.onClick.AddListener(ADDnrgdrainbtnclk);
        Button_ActivateMechanics.onClick.AddListener(SETactivatemechanicsbtnclk);
        Button_DeactivateMechanics.onClick.AddListener(SETdeactivatemechanicsbtnclk);
        Button_ResetValues.onClick.AddListener(SETresetbtnclk);


    }
    public void SETnrgbtnclk()  
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().SETnrg(Scriptcontainer_InputFields.GetComponent<Initialize_InputFields>().GETinputnrg());
    }
    public void SETnrgdrainbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().SETnrgdrain(Scriptcontainer_InputFields.GetComponent<Initialize_InputFields>().GETinputnrgdrainrate());
    }
    public void SETnrgdraincoefbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().SETnrgdraincoef(Scriptcontainer_InputFields.GetComponent<Initialize_InputFields>().GETinputnrgdraincoef());
    }    
    public void ADDnrgbtnclk()  
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().ADDnrg(Scriptcontainer_InputFields.GetComponent<Initialize_InputFields>().GETinputnrg());
    }
    public void ADDnrgdrainbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().ADDnrgdrain(Scriptcontainer_InputFields.GetComponent<Initialize_InputFields>().GETinputnrgdrainrate());
    }
    public void ADDnrgdraincoefbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().ADDnrgdraincoef(Scriptcontainer_InputFields.GetComponent<Initialize_InputFields>().GETinputnrgdraincoef());
    }    
    public void SETactivatemechanicsbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics.GetComponent<Drain_Mechanics>().SETdrainstate(true);
    }    
    public void SETdeactivatemechanicsbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_GameMechanics.GetComponent<Drain_Mechanics>().SETdrainstate(false);
    }    
    public void SETresetbtnclk()
    {
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().SETnrg(7950);
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().SETnrgdrain(0.09201389f);
        Scriptcontainer_Player.GetComponent<Player_Values>().SETnrgdraincoef(1.0f);
    }
}
```

at this point i apollogize one more time the amount of text im posting here but otherwise i cant even explain whats going on. and im not able to pick the exact codesnippets which are needed here. it will be better in future.

basically the main mechnisms work fine and im absolutely proud of what i did here...

my problems are the following.

Major problem 1. when i enter a value in the input fields and perform the button SET actions, i HAVE to do it in a specific order. NRG->DRAIN->COEF
otherwise the calculated textboxes are doing random stuff.

Major problem 2. when i try to perform the button add actions, the game also do random stuff. even when i set all variable to fixed values.

minor problem 3. in the Initialize_InputFields.cs im using the float.parse functionality. and my game constantly create warnings about a formatexception. is there a smarter way to solve this.

minor problem 4. last but not leat i want to work with realtime values. is there a way in unity to accerlate the globale timescale for the whole game?

Comment: In general avoid using `Find` at all! Serialize your fields and drag things together in the Inspector, if really needed have a central reference manager class and use `FindObjectOfType`, otherwise pass references on into runtime Instantiated objects .. usually there should be no good reason to use `Find` whatsoever

Comment: Also instead of using `GameObject` fields and then `GetComponent` over and over again rather store the actual component references and reuse those!